Tektronix 2000B series oscilloscope trigger not triggering camera
We have a Shimadzu high speed camera connected to a Tektronix oscilloscope. We got a new cord for the force sensor and since that point the camera has not been triggered correctly.
It used to be that we would set the threshold above the data noise and press "single". Then we would press "record" in the Shimadzu camera software and fire the projectile. When the projectile made contact with the force sensor the camera would trigger and the recording would save, and we would have the corresponding graph on the oscilloscope. Now the recording does not trigger. And it also does not trigger when we press the "force trig" button or the "run/stop" button from the 'single' mode. It now only triggers when we press the "run/stop" button twice to essentially start it up the second time.
Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this?

You need to decide where the trigger is 'born'. If it is the force sensor, the let it trigger all dependable devices, like camera and scope. Your actions will be to set everything, and when the force sensor gives its signal, the scope catches signal, and camera saves the video. Not triggering? You need to observe the trigger signal (from the force sensor). Also, consider this: Is one signal from force sensor capable of driving more than one inputs? If not, add amplifier, possibly with schmidt trigger.
